# Azure Rights Management Services Hosting

Tags: azure

I see an Azure Rights Management Services API.   From what I can tell it is to consume RMS.  Am I correct that Azure does not host the RMS Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be interested to know what have you found about "Azure Right Management API" as i don't think there is any Azure Management API specific to RMS solution.

Windows Azure does not provide a RMS based solution. Also RMS solution are integrated with AD and as of now you can not have AD running on Azure so you can not build such solution on Windows Azure. A few might state using the VM Role but it is not a solution as well.

Comment: The link that got me confused is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/bb968798(v=vs.85).aspx  It refers to RMS under windowazure.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, I will check with internal document guys to see if we can make documentation proper.  I would like to add that you sure can connect Azure Application to on-premise AD + RMS solution however that is far different then having a solution on Azure.

Comment: That makes sense.  If you are going to clean up documentation then maybe not refer to Active Directory in Access Control Service.  https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/access-control/   Azure is great but maybe too much reuse of terms.  Like TSQL is not the full the TSQL but still the same name.

Comment: Yes, I sure pass these comments to documentation team so they can at least get your feedback and take necessary action.

Answer (score 4):

I understand that the new to be released next year Office 365 Preview will have Rights Management Service. You can sign up for a trial today ( http://www.microsoft.com/office/preview/en/whats-new ). I also understand this is run from Azure.

Simon Skinner [MVP]

Answer (score 1):

AD RMS SDK2.1 RC actually lets you build applications that can work with both AD RMS (on-prem) and Azure AD RM (as part of Office 365). 
The SDK released few days ago, and is available at: https://connect.microsoft.com/site1170/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=48166.

(If you haven’t registered on Microsoft Connect, then: Go to connect.microsoft.com, sign in with your Microsoft Account > Directory> Search for Rights Management Services > Join)